# Github action to extract current version from package.json, increment the version and create the branch before running `npm version`

Tags: github, github-actions, git-flow

I'm currently writing an example set of workflows for a generic NPM based application. I'm currently working on creating a release branch which branches of Dev. This can be called via `workflow_dispatch` or `repository_dispatch`. The expected input is simply one of "Major", "Minor" or "Patch".

```yaml
name: Create Release

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      version_bump:
        type: choice
        description: "Update Major, Minor or Patch"
        options:
          - Major
          - Minor
          - Patch
        default: Patch
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [create_release]

    
      
env:    
 ...

jobs:
  create-release-branch:
    name: Create release Branch
    runs-on: [self-hosted, k8s-app-deploy]
    steps:

    - name: Validate Repo Dispatch inputs
      if: github.event_name == 'repository_dispatch'
      run: |
        case "${{ github.event.client_payload.version }}"
          Major)
          major)
            echo "VERSION=major" >> $GITHUB_ENV
            ;;

          Minor)
          minor)
            echo "VERSION=minor" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          ;;

          Patch)
          patch)
            echo "VERSION=patch" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          ;;

          *)
            echo 
            echo "::error title={Invalid Inputs}::{The inputs for the Repository Dispatch were wrong, needs to be Major, Minor or Patch}"
            exit 1
    - name: Validate Workflow Dispatch input
      if: github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch'
      run: echo VERSION=`echo ${{ inputs.version_bump }} | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - name:  Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        ref: "Develop"
    
    - run: git remote update

    - name: Set release verison
      run: |
        
    - run: git checkout -b release/$RELEASE_VERSION origin/Develop
```

The bit I'm stuck on is the step `Set release version`. To my knowledge, `npm version` can't create a new branch beforehand, nor would I want it to be there anyway, as I'd like to be able to create RC versions until we actually merge into main \ master and release the version.

My thought track is to

1. Extract the current version from the `package.json`,
2. Increment the correct number and set that as the `$RELEASE_VERSION`,
3. Create Release branch with `release/$RELEASE_VERSION`
4. Run `npm version $VERSION`
5. Push & create PR from release branch to main

I'll then have other workflows pickup from there.

My question is, how would you set the `$RELEASE_VERSION` variable?

Comment: Whats the difference between `RELEASE_VERSION` and `VERSION`?

Comment: You can use existing actions e.g. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/increment-semantic-version or https://github.com/marketplace/actions/version-increment to set `RELEASE_VERSION`.

Comment: @RobinThomas I should probably rename the `VERSION` variable, but it's the `major`, `minor` or `patch`. Basically, it's what's actually changing. `RELEASE_VERSION` is the number, eg: `1.0.1`

Comment: @Azeem Looking at `increment-semantic-version`, it looks like I need to tell it what the current version is. So if I was to use a one liner, like `node -e "console.log(require('./package.json').version);"` to set a variable called `CURRENT_VERSION` and then inject that to create the `RELEASE_VERSION`.